# How do I keep trying a web page that throws a "urllib2.HTTPError" error (python)?

Tags: python, html

I'm attempting to scrape the HTML from various webpages of a website.  However, I am occasionally getting the following error:

```
 urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 500: Internal Server Error
```

I'm trying to do a "while" loop to keep trying until the error goes away, but I haven't figured out the correct format for the loop.  It seems as though the website is a bit flaky, since it seems to fail on a different webpage each time.

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
web_raw_results = urllib2.urlopen(web_url)
while urllib2.HTTPError:
    web_raw_results = urllib2.urlopen(web_url)
```

But, that seems like it's doing just the opposite when I run it (it seems like it keeps repeatedly pulling the same webpage until it gets an error).

I'm pretty new to Python and I'm just messing around with a hobby project, so don't assume that I understand very much.  I'm sure I've made a stupid mistake, but I can't figure out what I did wrong.

Answer (score 10):

`urllib.urlopen` is throwing an [exception](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html).  You need to use the `try` and `except` statements to "catch" the exception, like this:

```
while True:
  try:
    web_raw_results = urllib2.urlopen(web_url)
    break
  except urllib.HTTPError:
    continue
```

This will loop continuously until the fetch succeeds.  You don't *really* want to do this; repeatedly requesting a URL in this sort of tight loop would probably be frowned upon by the server operator.  You might want to insert a delay before retrying, and you might want behave differently depending on whether or not you get a 500 error or something else.  Maybe:

```
while True:
  try:
    web_raw_results = urllib2.urlopen(web_url)
    break
  except urllib.HTTPError, detail:
    if detail.errno == 500:
      time.sleep(1)
      continue
    else:
      raise
```

This will pause for 1 second and continue the loop in the event of a
500 error; otherwise it will `raise` the exception (pass it on up the
call stack).

The [Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/index.html) has lots of good information.

Comment: Nothing like getting your answer posted, and finding that someone posted an even better answer already :-)

Comment: Actually, you're missing the break, as shown in my example. Yours will loop forever.

Answer (score 3):

I would do something like this:

```
import time
RETRY_TIME = 20.0
while True:
    try:
        web_raw_results = urllib2.urlopen(web_url)
        break
    except urllib2.HTTPError:
        time.sleep(RETRY_TIME)
        pass
```